# Tips on running perl in VS2013/VS2019 Post Build Event

Tags: perl, visual-studio-2013

I don't yet have a test case for this, and am still digging.
I have created a nifty binary file editing perl script that back annotates some binary builds which are the output of a propriatary compiler we use.  I want to have this back annotation done as a post build step.
When I run the script in powershell on the binary files, it works fine.
When I run it as a post build event, it crashes with:

```
1>  Perl5LIB is   C:/StrawberryPerl/perl/site/lib;C:/StrawberryPerl/perl/vendor/lib;C:/StrawberryPerl/perl/lib
1>  Invalid type 'Q' in pack at C:/StrawberryPerl/perl/lib/Config_heavy.pl line 1354.
1>  Compilation failed in require at C:/StrawberryPerl/perl/lib/Config.pm line 80.
1>  BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:/StrawberryPerl/perl/lib/Tie/RefHash.pm line 109.
1>  Compilation failed in require at C:/StrawberryPerl/perl/lib/Fatal.pm line 9.
1>  BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:/StrawberryPerl/perl/lib/Fatal.pm line 9.
1>  Compilation failed in require at C:/StrawberryPerl/perl/lib/parent.pm line 16.
1>  BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:/StrawberryPerl/perl/lib/autodie.pm line 6.
1>  Compilation failed in require at C:\APPSWARE\SuperMuxDummyDutTC\LogicDDRDLL\..\SmuxFixer.pl line 7.
```

So far I found initialy that @INC in the Visual Studio environment wasn't set to the same as the PowerShell environment... so I defined PERL5LIB and it's now picking up and reporting the same @INC as in PowerShell... but clearly something else is different.  (I'd add %25PATH%25 too, but at the moment it contains strings I'd need to vet).

Just wondering if there are others using Perl Scripts in post build events and have some pointers on the care and feeding of them.
We supply a version of Perl with our software distribution, which differs from Strawberry Perl, so I have to dig in and see if there aren't other things pointing to different perls etc.

I'll try to update this as I learn more.

Comment: Thanks for the edit.

Comment: Those  locations shouldn't be in `PERL5LIB`. These are for one specific Perl install that can already locate them there.

Comment: ?What locations should be in PERL5LIB?  Locations for a specific Perl Install that can already locate them there?  If it can already locate them there, why do they need to be there?   So from your comment I get A)"I'm doing it wrong" OK, that's highly likely, but 2)What is PERL5LIB for then if not to provide a path for PERL to search for libs

Comment: Re "*If it can already locate them there, why do they need to be there?*", They don't. That's my point. Or they're modules installed by a different `perl`. Also bad to use.

Comment: Re "*What locations should be in PERL5LIB?*", If you directed a module installer to install a module in a non-standard directory, the lib directories of that directory should be added. When using StrawberryPerl, I've never had to to use a non-standard directory, but a user with fewer permissions might.

Comment: Re "*What is PERL5LIB for then if not to provide a path for PERL to search for libs*", `@INC` is where Perl looks. `@INC` doesn't start empty. `PERL5LIB` allows one to add to `@INC`. It's for users that don't have sufficient permissions to install to the normal directory or decide to install a module elsewhere for some other reason.

Comment: The name of the language is Perl, not PERL. It's not an acronym

Answer (score 1):

I determined the issue to be $PATH related.
There are two $PATH environment variables that our software tracks, the typical %PATH%, and another for Visual Studio which is (or used to be) kept in the registry.
Our release change software updates both so that all our *.exe files and our *.dll packages can be found by the runtime and Visual Studio when users change releases.

We distribute a version of perl with our systems, in my case, that perl was too old, so I used a recent Strawberry Perl version.  When we switch releases, we detect if an alternate perl exists and ask if the user wishes that version to be placed first in %PATH%.

I must have failed to do this.  And for some reason there is a dependancy in StrawBerryPerl that is tied to %PATH% and not @INC.  I also discovered that setting PERL5LIB explicitly to point to StrawBerryPerls @INC path, will break our release swapping code.   For the moment, I don't care to drill down to exactly why.  In a nutshell this was a %25PATH%25 issue I believe.

Comment: Re "*in my case, that perl was too old*", More precisely, it was a 32-bit build that used the internal Config.pm of a 64-bit build.